# How do you organise your ATG projects?

Tags: atg, atg-dynamo

If you develop for ATG Dynamo, how do you structure your modules and dependencies?

How do you structure the projects? source directories, JARs configs etc.

How do you build and deploy? What tools do you use?

Answer (score 6):

We have a monolithic architecture with a single ATG module. We originally developed this site with JHTML and have since created a (monolithic) J2EE web app within this ATG module and converted all of our JHTML to JSP.

Our project on disk looks like this:

```
root
  deploy
    class (compile java to here)
    config (primary configpath)
    docroot (JHTML docroot)
    dev (configpath for dev environment)
    test (configpath for QA environment)
    prod (configpath for prod environment)
  j2ee (j2ee web-app)
    WEB-INF
    dir-a (application JSPs)
    dir-b (application JSPs)
  src
    java (java src)
    sql (sql src)
```

We have an Ant build file that compiles the Java source to deploy/class. On dev/test and prod JAR up. We have a single build server that checks out the CVS repository and uses shell scripts and the build.xml to compile and deploy to the requested server using Interwoven OpenDeploy (essentially rsync).

Answer (score 2):

Most structures look like the ones mentioned above with minor changes. 
We use MAVEN to build and deploy.

Comment: How do you get around the runassembler ?

Comment: Could you tell us how to using maven to bulid and deploy atg project?thanks.

Comment: I all ATG projects I have seen they ended up using Ant plugin to call runassembler Ant task.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the layout that we use:

root
 src (java src)
 test/src (unit test)
 build (directory created by ant)
   classes
   config
   javadoc
   lib
   liveconfig
 buildlib (libraries used for building)
 config
 install (holds items used for different IDE)
 j2ee-apps
 lib (libraries used by the application)
 sql
   oracle
   data
   install (tables, indexes etc)
   setup (create tablespace, users etc)
   uninstall
   delta  (changes during development)

Answer (score 1):

Very similar to the above (no Maven). Plus the groovy directory - we use lot of groovy scripts for deployment/building related task (Ant in combination with Antbuilder)