# Creation of war file from an ATG project

Tags: eclipse, weblogic, atg

How to create a war file from an ATG project in eclipse? I am using eclipse to create ATG project.

Comment: What have you done so far? Have you looked at the runAssembler `ant` tasks that exist? Why are you trying to build an ATG project in Eclipse? Are you trying to do hot-deploys?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you organise your ATG projects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205557/how-do-you-organise-your-atg-projects)